# GCC compiler cannot compile Hello World program

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the default `Hello World` on Code Blocks with the `GNU GCC` compiler but am getting the result of

> cannot find -lbgi

It would be really helpful because right now I can't do a single thing!

Earlier I tried to use `graphics.h` and downloaded `libbgi.a` and I thought that was the problem so I deleted it. However, the compiler still produced the same error for the Hello World program, as well as previous programs that I made with C. From these information I guess that the problem is in the compiler but I cannot figure out what is causing it.

```cpp
    //c++ hello world program
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

---

```
    //c hello world program
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){
        printf("Hello world!\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

I expect `Hello World` to be the output.

however:

```
||=== Build: Debug in firstCppProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lbgi|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: What is the command you ran to compile?

Comment: @BrandonDyer Code::Blocks is an IDE.

Comment: I am not trying to link the library 'BGI' and I do not know what it is.

Comment: Which version of Code::Blocks? What steps did you follow, exactly?

Comment: BGI is Borland Graphics Interface

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks17.12

Comment: Somehow you have told Code Blocks to link with libbgi.a, and Code BLocks is telling you that it can't. So now you've got to find a way to tell Code Blocks that you're not interested in libbgi.a after all. I'd tell you how but unfortunately I don't know Code Blocks

Comment: Can I somehow unlink it from the project or whatever it is linked to?

Comment: You still need to add _detailed reproduction steps_ to your question. Tell us _exactly_ what you did to your Code::Blocks installation. How did you configure it? Did you install any packages? Which buttons did you press? Right now this is just very vague (and that's why my answer is also, necessarily, vague).

Comment: Hi dude the. If you are inerested in earning some reputation, which gives all kinds of advantages here, you can improve your question post. That will be quite easy now, because many improvements are much easier in hindsight, now that you know the solution. Getting the question reopened AND probably earning some upvotes might take nothing more than adding those details which you now know, about where/what/how you configured (accidentally) to cause the linker to attempt linking the lib in question. Just add the info whcih would have immediatly allowed to answer in detail. And accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a Console application ([steps](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project)).

Currently you seem to be using a project created using a template with settings for Borland-compatible graphics (using a port of the old Turbo C++ "graphics" libraries), but you have deleted the libraries required to make that work.

Alternatively, you could remove the dependency on BGI from your project's linker settings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just realized that I wrote some things in the linker settings. Now it's all fixed. I'm so stupid :( Just wasted so much time

Comment: Yeah... Well that's how life works. It's all about wasting time and then learning from that mistake. It's my first time using Stack Overflow so next time I'll make sure explain with more detail.